Notification icon that looks like this
Notification icon that looks like this
Please excuse my poor attempt to recreate it


A screenshot would be a lot more helpful... Plus you can usually long-press the notification in the pull-down shade to see what app is putting it there.

Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. If you're the device owner, please try the following method. Otherwise, since there are millions of Android apps and more for notification icons, the community can't help anymore in identifying a specific icon of an app.
